# How to automatically create new Product Code on build with InstallShield?

Tags: installshield, installshield-le

I've just recently learned that by generating a new product code in InstallShield, the installer will upgrade previous version of your software instead of requiring the user to first uninstall a previous version. This is a great first step, however it's still seems to like I should be able to automate the process of generating a new product code every time I build. Currently I have to manually remember to do this before building a new installer.

I'm using InstallShield LE 2015, so I'm not sure if this might be a limitation of the LE version or not. Can someone more experienced with InstallShield Please explain if it's possible and how I go about setting this up please?

Answer (score 1):

The ProductCode is stored as a property, so you can edit your .islproj file (or whatever the name it uses is for the msbuild-syntax project file) to specify a new guid value for that property. Follow the approach outlined in [Customizing the .isproj File](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MSBuild.htm) by adding an ItemGroup similar to the following. Note that this example assumes you have somehow provided a valid GUID in `$(MyNewProductCode)`.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <InstallShieldPropertyOverrides Include="$(MyNewProductCode)">
       <Property>ProductCode</Property>
   </InstallShieldPropertyOverrides>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you building via command line or through msbuild or some automated method? If you are, you can use the below method:

```
:: Change Product Code for Build
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\x64\uuidgen.exe"') DO SET productcodeguidcl=%%i
"C:\PATHTOFNR\fnr.exe" --cl --dir "C:\PATHTOYOURISM" --fileMask "YOUR.ism" --useRegEx --alwaysUseEncoding "utf-8" --find "ProductCode.*{.*}" --replace "ProductCode</td><td>{%productcodeguidcl%}"
```

Note the following example assumes you have uuidgen.exe (free) on the build server and also requires the free tool fnr.exe (https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/)

We used this for Basic MSI's, Installscript MSI's and Installscript projects awhile without any issues until we finally switched our project over to Installshield API's.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Michael Urman's answer above, I was able to generate the new GUID directly from within the .isproj file by using a [property function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx).  When my CI machine builds my install shield project, the product code is automatically updated using this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <InstallShieldPropertyOverrides Include="{$([System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper())}">
       <Property>ProductCode</Property>
   </InstallShieldPropertyOverrides>
</ItemGroup>
```

Hooray for automation.